# Integrar pantallas Unity con activities en Java

Tags: android, unity3d

Necesito unir ciertas partes de un juego hecho en Unity con una app android, es posible?
Es decir, poner una introducción tipo juego con unity y luego usar activities propias de Android.

Algo parecido a unir java con react native.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí que se puede, al menos en unity 5.3 en adelante puedes exportar tu proyecto de unity a Android Studio. Dependiendo de cual es tu actividad principal te puede interesar empezar en la de unity y mostrar tus actividades de android por encima, o al reves, empezar en la de Android y luego mostrar la de unity.

Si tienes conocimientos de Android es tan facil como cambiar el intent-filter en el manifest.

Para llamar a código nativo desde Unity y cambiar de Actividad lo más fácil en este caso es añadir una funcion estatica a la clase UnityPlayerActivity para mostrar la otra actividad, por ejemplo:

```
 AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.myorganizacion.mypaquete.UnityPlayerActivity");
 jc.CallStatic("mostrarActividadNativa");
```

mostrarActividadNativa sería tu función estática que hace un startActivity de tu actividad nativa en Android.

Comment: Gracias! muy interesante saber que se puede hacer

Comment: no entiendo muy bien, lo que he puesto es para desde la actividad de unity mostrar la actividad nativa. Para mostrar la actividad de unity desde una nativa es tan facil como hacer un startActivity de la actividad UnityPlayerActivity